# DAX cannot compare text and integers, but no reference columns are text

Tags: powerbi, comparison, dax

I've created a measure like this:

```
Measure =
DIVIDE (
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( fact_table[Net Amount Paid] ),
        FILTER (
            ALLSELECTED ( fact_table ),
            RELATED ( date_table[Date] ) <= MAX ( date_table[Date] )
        ),
        FILTER ( id_table, id_table[ID] = "12345" )
    ),
    1000000,
    0
)
```

This measure is meant to sum the net amount paid in fact_table, when the ID in id_table is 12345, then divide the sum by the budget of $1M. However, I keep getting the error that "DAX comparison operators do not support comparing values of type integer with type text."

I've checked and none of the columns referenced in my measure are of type text, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter is specifying `"12345"` as text. To treat it as a number, remove the quotes around it.